# Set Outlook rule on Users mailbox remotely

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, office365

I want to remotely configure an Outlook rule with PowerShell that will forward meeting invitations and updates to another user.

Step 1) Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName

Step 2) Set-InboxRule XXXX@fakecompany.com\ForwardTo -which is a meeting or invitation or update -ForwardTo YYYY@fakecompany.com

The issue is I can not find the parameter "Which is a meeting or Update".

Comment: Reference link: New-TransportRule
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-transportrule?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking to do is use `MessageTypeMatches`

`New-InboxRule -Mailbox 'xxx@fakecompany.com' -Name 'FWD Meeting updates' -MessageTypeMatches CalendaringResponse -ForwardTo "yyy@fakecompany.com" -StopProcessingRules:$true`